# Rails and Devise: undefined method `to' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would be immensely grateful for your help. I have begun setting up a rails app with devise and have had difficulty with my authentification. I have got to the point where I can create a new user and sign out, but I cannot login as a registered user. Currently, sign in attempt throws the error below. Signin is correctly going to the sessions#create controller, but the warden line is redirecting to failure app file on devise and throwing this error. Any help is greatly appreciated! For your information, I am also including my routes and SessionsController.

[Image of Error on Signin Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3emdM.png)

[Devise routes in routes.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SkIe.png)

[Devise SessionsController #new and #create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhmc8.png)

Comment: You have a typo in one of your files (passswords in routes.rb); not sure if that might affect things. Generally it is appreciated if you put the code text in the question rather than use images.

Comment: In addition to what Ben said in the first comment, you probably have a syntax error in `routes.rb` file, instead of `as :user do` block it should be `devise_scope :users do` block I think

Comment: @Deepesh apparently, it's an [alias](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/main/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#devise_scope-instance_method). Emily, if you're trying to override controllers: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-controllers. However, devise already does authentication work for you and you should have a good reason for overriding controllers.